# FB Post text as Status Update for a Page

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've looked into the Facebook Javascript SDK and can't seem to find a way to simply post a textual status update, specifically as a Page.

For Twitter I can use the url - https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hello%20world - which will redirect the user to twitter where they can login and just press Tweet.

I just wanted to double check there wasn't anything available for Facebook with a similar functionality. Ideally I don't want to have to get an APPID or anything beforehand, and just let the user log in and post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use URL redirection but I guess you will still an app id regardless and it doesn't work if you are posting as a page. From the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.4):

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=145634995501895
  &display=popup&caption=An%20example%20caption 
  &link=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F
  &redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
```

Alternatively, you can use the Facebook JS SDK and use the feed dialog to be able to post as a page:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
  caption: 'An example caption',
  from: 'Your page id',
}, function(response){});
```